# Protocol error swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I am a newbie to programming but the problem is the the ViewController . I am using core graphics to create a shape accordingly. Error to display view controller to segue to display the page.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,CustomViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var sliderSmile: UISlider!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        let defaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let x:CGFloat = CGFloat(defaults.floatForKey("currentImagePosX"))
        let y:CGFloat = CGFloat(defaults.floatForKey("currentImagePosY"))
        //make a point
        //get a ref to the view
        let view = self.view as! CustomView
        //the crucial line
        view.delegate = self

        view.defaultPos.x = x
        view.defaultPos.y = y





    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func smileValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {

        let customView = self.view as! CustomView
        customView.setSmile = CGFloat (sender.value)

    }

}
```

Delegate

---

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol CustomViewDelegate
{

    func upDateImagePosition(currentPos: CGPoint)

}
```

Error to display view controller to segue to display the page.

```
2016-05-19 03:15:30.050 Usmaan [20208:1816738] Unknown class _TtC7Usmaan_8Graphics in Interface Builder file.
2016-05-19 03:15:30.080 Usmaan [20208:1816738] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fcc0b7fbc80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key sliderSmile.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c5ee65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bbc6deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c5eaa9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010a24f9bb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010a832320 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010aa60f41 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109b9f4a0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010aa5f924 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010a838eea -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010a839816 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010a839b74 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010a83ff4f -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 120
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010a86fe44 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1203
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010a88023f -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010a8813af -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010aa27ff7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010a75a4a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f73359a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f727e70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f727cee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f71c475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f749c0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010a69df7c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7329
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109b8aa31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109b8095c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109b7fe13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109b7f828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010f1e8ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010a6a3610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    29  Usmaan                              0x00000001096a50dd main + 109
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010c6d892d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Please show us the delegate

Comment: done            ................

Comment: Your view controller does not conform to `CustomViewDelegate` because you haven't implemented `upDateImagePosition`.

Comment: thank you. Also have a problem with Exception Error to display core graphics. Segue onto the ViewController screen

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `upDateImagePosition` in your View Controller. Otherwise, the controller doesn't conform to the methods and properties set out in the protocol. See documentation on protocols for more details: [Apple docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjvtvufiOXMAhWLtBQKHeZBA04QFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FSwift%2FConceptual%2FSwift_Programming_Language%2FProtocols.html&usg=AFQjCNEyd1wXBiDJzr6Fog_CVKofL-mAUA&sig2=kN0dby0B8hoNNUWQNFvKIw)

Comment: thank you. Also have a problem with Exception Error to display core graphics. Segue onto the ViewController screen. The application delegate displays a error

Comment: @UsmaanGill http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reasonthis-class-is-not-key-valu